# Not able to remove a specific character from file via ansible

Tags: python, linux, ansible

I have a file with below data

```
server1 10.10.10.10,
server2 10.10.10.20,
server3 10.10.10.30,
```

And would like to only delete the comma character(`,`) from the third line i.e from `server3 10.10.10.30.`

When I try to use `lineinfile` method, it removes all the commas, but my requirement is to remove the comma only from the third line.

I was wondering if there is any method that we can use in ansible to remove the character from line x, row y to be more precise?

Thank you in advance for your time and response.

Comment: Did I answer your question? If not, what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `lineinfile` module does not seem appropriate for your scenario. You could instead use the `sed` command:

```
- shell: sed -i 3s/,$// filetochange
```